# Setting values to elements of a 2D array of user defined size

Tags: c, malloc, user-input, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to use the malloc() function to create a square grid (2D array) with the value of each element in the array to be 0.

The size of the array must be assigned by the user and then each element set to zero.

I then try to write the elements of the grid to file and print them but even though I have tried to ensure they are all 0, they are printed out as large numbers.

Here is the code I have written:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    int     side, part_max, side_mid;
    int     i, j;
    int     **grid;

    FILE    *outmid;

    outmid = fopen("test.out", "w");
    if(outmid == (FILE*) NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open outmid file\n");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Enter the size of each side of the square grid\n");
    scanf("%d", &side);                                             
    printf("side = %d\n", side);

    grid = (int**)malloc(side*sizeof(int*));                    
    if(grid == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(i=0; i<side; i++)
    {
        grid[i] = (int*)malloc(side*sizeof(int));
        if(grid[i] == NULL)
        {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }       
    }

    for(i=0; i<side; i++) /*ensures grid is filled with zeros*/
    {
        for(j=0; j<side; j++)   
        {
        grid[i][j] = 0;
        fprintf(outmid, "%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, j, &grid[i][j]);                                 
        printf("co-ordinates of %d\t%d\t%d written to file\n", i, j, &grid[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and runs but the only problem I have is that I can't assign the values of the elements to be 0.

So the question I am asking is how do you create an array of user defined size and then assign a value to each element, not knowing what size the user is going to choose?

UPDATE 5 years on: 
I highly doubt it but incase anyone comes across this and wants to know the answer..

The issue was with my call to printf(). Here as the final argument I pass the address of the (i, j)th element in the grid, not the value.. So the values would have been initialized properly but I was printing the value of a pointer to it..

Comment: `fprintf(outmid, "%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, j, &grid[i][j]);` --> `fprintf(outmid, "%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, j, grid[i][j]);` : remove `&`. and `printf` ditto.

Comment: That's it, thank you BLUEPIXY . I'm new to this site so don't really know what I'm doing

Comment: @Henry Your edit should be posted as an answer, not as an edit to the question. It is perfectly fine to answer your own questions here.

Answer (score 1):

```
grid[i] = (int*)malloc(side, sizeof(int));
```

malloc only takes one parameter, unlike calloc. I'm surprised that the code compiles at all. Change it to

```
grid[i] = malloc(side * sizeof(int));
```

(There is never any reason to cast the result of malloc in C)

Comment: That was my mistake, I was messing around with malloc and calloc and forgot to change that , to a *.

Comment: The question still remains with the *, it doesn't compile with the ,